# Increment counter field in database (saving load database) 

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, counter

Scenario: A database keeps several counters that are updated frequently.

The update statement is simple:

```
UPDATE table SET count = count + 1
```

However, the updates are very frequent (not required show updated value constantly), so that it might be appropriate to find a way to upgrade in blocks (for save connections):

Instead of +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1 in short time periods (every one or few seconds), make a +80 in long time periods blocks (every 5 minutes).

How I can update counter value for save frequent connections?

(Note: I see **UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY** in MySQL databases, I find things similar)

Comment: You didn't specify a DBMS but if yours support triggers, do that in a trigger and it will be transparent for you

Comment: But... Where save these increment numbers temporary? What would be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter is a very simple thing. You could save the number in a text file if you want. Saving to a local file is usually easier on the server than running a query on the database and it sounds like you are already interested in reducing the load on the database. Use a file block (such as [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)) if you are worried about the race condition; then have a script synchronize the database with the text file(s) with the frequency you think is appropriate (perhaps using a [cron job](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)).

Answer (score 0):

Auto-answer: I found fast and efficient system for temporary storage (instead of file):

- Redis: http://redis.io/ (ideally, persistent)
- Memcached: http://memcached.org/